# Informix SP not returning mapped beans with MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, informix

We have an Informix Stored Procedure that works perfectly, goes to the database and returns us some registers with various values.

The problem comes when we want to use this SP on MyBatis. We have a test case where we are calling a method that invokes the stored procedure with a mapper, and when we execute it, it seems that it did his job (the list's size is 5, the same number of registers the SP on the database returns) but all of the registers are nulls.

We think that the mapper is not mapping the values to the bean, so the registers are null. But we are not sure.

We are calling the store procedure like this

```
      <select id="requestAllCoberturasPlan"
      parameterType="RequestCoberturasPlanEvent"          
      statementType="CALLABLE">

{
    #{lstCoberturasPlan, jdbcType=CURSOR, mode=OUT, resultMap=requestAllCoberturasPlanResultMap, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet} =
    call sp_plan_cobervida
    (
        #{cveLinea, jdbcType = SMALLINT, mode = IN},
        #{cveProd, jdbcType = SMALLINT, mode = IN},
        #{cvePlan, jdbcType = SMALLINT, mode = IN},
        #{idSolicitud, jdbcType = SMALLINT, mode = IN}
    )
}
    </select>
```

Does anybody face a problem like that? Please, we need all the help we can.

Comment: Could you post a working example for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the out parameter part of the procedure call. Simply use this

```
<select id="requestAllCoberturasPlan"
  parameterType="RequestCoberturasPlanEvent"          
  statementType="CALLABLE" resultMap=requestAllCoberturasPlanResultMap>
{call sp_plan_cobervida
    (
    #{cveLinea, jdbcType = SMALLINT, mode = IN},
    #{cveProd, jdbcType = SMALLINT, mode = IN},
    #{cvePlan, jdbcType = SMALLINT, mode = IN},
    #{idSolicitud, jdbcType = SMALLINT, mode = IN}
    )
 }
</select>
```

take a look at this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mybatis/mybatis_stored_procedures.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Informix Stored Procedures it's important to name return parameters.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.udr.doc/ids_udr_096.htm

```
The syntax for the CREATE PROCEDURE/FUNCTION statement is:
RETURNS/RETURNING data_type AS return_param_name [{, data_type AS
return_param_name}]
```